# How to configure Sails.js for SPA using multiple .html files

Tags: sails.js, single-page-application

From the Sails.js docs you can find that to deal with SPA you can add index.html file directly into assets/ directory.
But what if I want to have 2 index.html with different SPAs.
For example:
 assets/index.html
 assets/admin.html

I want these to be available through http://host/ and http://host/admin. How do I configure sails for that?

Comment: Would it not work to just create a directory for admin? like "/admin/index.html"